# Audio automatically plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I was on here a minute ago looking to find a way to do this, and it came up with this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'mixtaperainbow.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    //audioElement.load()

    $.get();

    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.Play();
    }, true);

    $('.Play').click(function() {
        audioElement.Play();
    });

    $('.Stop').click(function() {
        audioElement.Stop();
    });
});
```

But I can't get it not to autoplay the sound... someone please help <3

Comment: well you have the attribute set to auto play? maybe comment out this line audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');

Comment: @floor I've tried that but then it just doesn't work at all.

Comment: when you comment out that line do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @floor nothing is showing in console

Comment: is there any error when you click play?

Comment: @FreeCommercial, this works for me, with some changes: http://jsfiddle.net/ytqtocof/

Comment: @floor console is empty @ nevermind that still automatically plays the mp3 file, where that is the opposite of what i want it to to (i want ti have to click play first)

Comment: Aaaah, soo... i'm tired, just remove:   audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay'); :)

Comment: which works... which is what I said.... remove that line of code tested and works in the fiddle

Comment: @nevermind hmm... I did it in my actual html file, and didn't work, but it does seem to work on the jsfiddle... weird.

Comment: @FreeCommercial what does your html look like?

Comment: @floor haha as I typed that last comment I was thinking the same thing you were, I check my html and the button was calling "play" and not "Play" lol thanks for the help though I seriously appreciate it !

Comment: you too @nevermind ! <3